# Touchpad right click not working in 13.04, ASUS B400A-XH51

Tags: touchpad, asus, synaptics, trackpad

I've just put Ubuntu 13.04 on my ASUS B400A-XH51 laptop and am having a problem with the touchpad: It has discrete left and right buttons, and the left one works fine, but the right one does nothing when pressed. (I can still do a right click by using a two-finger tap, although I would rather disable tapping and just use the discrete buttons.)

Also, if I put my finger on the lower-right area of the touchpad while clicking the discrete left button, it acts as a right-click -- as though Ubuntu thinks it is a clickpad.

Any ideas for how to make the right button work?

(Similar to an issue with ASUS G46VW: https://askubuntu.com/questions/311296/ordinary-two-button-touchpad-incorrectly-detected-as-clickpad#new-answer)

Here is the output of "xinput --list"

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad                  id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam                      id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus WMI hotkeys                          id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Comment: Please the output of `xinput --list`

Comment: The output of `synclient` is more informative imho